# Elastic APM dotnet yarp display all traces

Tags: .net-core, kibana, elastic-apm, ms-yarp

Kibana version: 8.5.1

Elasticsearch version: 8.5.1

APM Server version: 8.5.1

APM Agent language and version: Elastic.Apm.NetCoreAll 1.23.0

I'm using api gateway (Yarp reverse proxy) in front of all microservices. I have installed Elastic.Apm.NetCoreAll in all services + gateway.

This is how apm config looks like in all services and gateway:

```
"ElasticApm": {
  "ServerUrl": "myapmurl",
  "TransactionSampleRate": 1
}
```

When I check some request in kibana apm in some service, I see all details, sub requests from svc1 to svc2, from svc2 to svc3, db calls etc.
When I check same request in Api gateway, I see only one http request, no other details.

[image]

TraceParent and TraceState headers are passed from gateway to microservices.
Is there any additional setup I need to do to make APM work correctly with yarp?